# HttpWebRequest() timeout not respected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using a HttpWebRequest and a WebProxy to test some proxy servers to see if they are still functional or not. I set up the timeout to 1000 milliseconds but in some cases the program times out after more than 20 seconds. This happens in the catch loop. Is there a way to fix this? I don't want to wait more than 2 seconds for a proxy. I am using .Net 4.5.2

```
    string GetPageThroughProxy(string sUrl, string sHost, string sProxyIPAddress, string sProxyPort, string sUsername, string sPassword)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;              

        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sUrl);
        
        string proxyAddress = sProxyIPAddress;
        string proxyPort = sProxyPort;
        
        string username = sUsername; 
        string password = sPassword; 
        
        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(proxyAddress + ":" + proxyPort);         
        wp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;           
        wp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        httpWebRequest.Proxy = wp;  
        
        string sReferer = sUrl;
        
        httpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        
        httpWebRequest.UserAgent = Variables.userAgent; // "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36 Edg/84.0.522.40";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = Variables.reqAccept; // "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9";
        
        httpWebRequest.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate, br";
        httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;                   
        httpWebRequest.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.9";
        
        httpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 2;
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        
        httpWebRequest.Referer = sReferer;
        httpWebRequest.Timeout = 1000;
        httpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000;         

        try {
            WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            string responseFromServer = string.Empty;
            stopwatch.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show(stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff"));
            
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        
            response.Close();
            return responseFromServer;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception " + ex.Message + "\n\n" + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff"));
        }
        
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Do you consider to use HttpClient instead of httpWebRequest?

Comment: Sure, if it does the job. Although I would like to know why the Timeout property is not working in my example.

Comment: Shouldn't your stopwatch start just before the getresponse() call?

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this case. I don't care about milliseconds.

Comment: The `HttpWebRequest.Timeout` applies to the GET request (`GetResposnse()` and `GetResponseStream()`). It doesn't apply to Proxy redirections or the DNS resolver. If you're passing addresses that need a DNS lookup, the Timeout is 15 seconds. After that the Web Request can actually begin and the Timeout you have set applies. -- You have a number of issues in this setup: why are you setting a Referer is unknown and trying this: `HttpVersion.Version11` is meaningless. The `Accept-Encoding` is not set like that and including br (not supported in `"gzip, deflate, br"`) is looking for trouble etc.

Comment: So is trying to limit the maximum redirections when the redirections needed to reach the final destination is unknown in advance, or setting `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true` (which, btw, is the default but this is not a `PUT` or `POST` request); in any case, if you keep `Expect100Continue = true` (when it will be actually used), **you need to handle it**. -- If you need to know whether a Server is active AND you want to set a Timeout, you need to bypass the proxy and resolve the DNS name beforehand.

Comment: Another - really important - detail: if you **need** to set a `UserAgent` header, it **must** be a WebBrowser header that doesn't support [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). If the WebBrowser version specified does support HSTS and also the Server has HSTS active (or it can be activated), it will wait for the Client *interaction* (an active response) and will use its own Timeout to reject the Request if no response is received. Which can cause, in your case, false negatives. In normal Requests, it will cause an answerable Request to Timeout.

Comment: Jimi, thank you very much for your comments. I removed just about all lines that you mentioned. I only pass IP addresses, so no DNS lookups. I still have checks that take a long time (about 25% of my tested IP take over 20 seconds).

Comment: I cannot see the code you're mentioning. + You have set a Proxy there: the time you need to pass through a Proxy is not considered. The time needed to get a Route from both DNS and routers/other Network adapters is not considered. The ServicePointManager ability to find ServicePoints for your requests and enqueue the requests if the connection limit is reached is not considered. `Expect100Continue` must be set to `false`, since the time to wait for `100Continue` response is not considered... Make async requests and pass a CancellationToken with a Timeout set and Handle the Timeout exception.